# Given a value, and a dataset with two classes, what is the probability that it belongs to each class?

Tags: distributions, classification

I have a dataset of continuous values from 0.0-1.0 with two possible class labels (say 30% are 'red' and 70% are 'blue'). Given a random value between 0.0-1.0, I want to give the probability that it belongs in the 'red' class and the probability that it belongs in the 'blue' class.

I assume this means I need to observe the probability distributions of the data, and then do some kind of test (t-test?) based on these distributions.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean that 30% of the value range from 0.0 to 1.0 defines a red event versus 80% of the range that is blue, and that you do not know the probability distribution of those values across the range of numbers? If so, is your goal to simulate these outcomes, or do some type of inference?

Comment: I do know the distributions of those values, so I can observe the distributions directly. The 30/70 doesn't refer to the ranges, only to the total number of values which are labeled red/blue. Most "reds" are closer to 0.0 and most blues are closer to 1.0.

My goal is to calculate the class probabilities for any new value I receive in the range 0.0 to 1.0, based on the value and on the distributions that I've already observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more complex equation that can be used as a solution to my problem, but here's what I did:

1) Divide the 0.0-1.0 range up into bins ('sub-ranges'). I used Sturges' rule, which recommended a bin width of 0.14, but instead chose 0.10, just because it's less confusing.

2) For each bin, I gathered the total number of samples falling in that range. I tallied up the reds and blues and used those to create two lists of probabilities (one for each class) for all of the 10 ranges.

3) End up with two lists: one showing the probabilities that a value could be red if it fell within a given range, and one showing similar probabilities for blue.

Example:

In the range 0.0-0.1, I observe in my dataset that I have 40 reds and 60 blues. I am given a new value of 0.05. Since it falls within this range of 0.0-0.1, I use the statistic of my dataset to calculate the probability and get: 40% chance that it's red, and 60% chance that it's blue.

It's not necessarily the most precise or mathematical solution I imagine, but it communicates some information at least.